# How to add field for Video uploading in drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, cck

i am new to Drupal and using drupal 7,i have a content type.i added few fields in that,now i want to add another filed for video uploading. how to add this field?

Comment: You can easily find a module on drupal.org if you give a try to the 'search box' on drupal.org!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to have videos uploaded to YouTube and then added to your website via [Youtube Field](http://drupal.org/project/youtube). This saves you a great deal of traffic, storage space, CPU and RAM.

If you insist on having videos uploaded to your website, consider using [Video](http://drupal.org/project/video).